# What is the maximum size of message that can be transferred from one bolt to another in a topology

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I have a topology in build using streamparse, it receives input from kafka and later spout transmits the message to master bolt, 
Master bolt computes and generates 10 MB of message and this message must be passed to other 3 bolts.

The data is getting generated successfully in the master bolt, but getting the following error while it is getting transferred to the other Bolt

`ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:localhost:514 for appender syslog: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error flushing stream UDP:localhost:514`

Answer (score 0):

The log you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with message size. It's saying it can't write a log to localhost:514. Maybe your logging is misconfigured?

As far as I know, the maximum message size is solely determined by your max heap size, so it will depend on your RAM and JVM configuration. I'd be surprised if you're hitting a limit at 10 MB.

Comment: I am executing the topology in python using streamparse and doing further search i found that the size of message that can be transmitted from one bolt to another is 64KB